# How to get keys and values of jsonb array for a record (row) from inside PL/lpgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, jsonb

I have a text column in a table that contains city/country type of data, convertible to jsonb, such as:

```
SELECT 
        '{"Toronto":"Canada","Moscow":"Russia","New York":"USA"}'::text 
AS city_data
```

and I have to convert it to a `JSONB` array of this format:

```
[
    {
        "city": "Moscow",
        "match": false,
        "country": "Russia"
    },
    {
        "city": "Toronto",
        "match": false,
        "country": "Canada"
    },
    {
        "city": "New York",
        "match": false,
        "country": "USA"
    }
]
```

I am able to do it in a regular PostgreSQL query, by first getting each key/value, and then aggregating it back to JSONB array.

```
WITH data AS (
    WITH city_table AS (
        SELECT 
        '{"Toronto":"Canada","Moscow":"Russia","New York":"USA"}'::text AS city_data
            )
    SELECT cities.key AS city, cities.value AS country
    FROM city_table
    LEFT JOIN jsonb_each_text(city_data::jsonb) cities ON true
              )
SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
'city', city::text, 
'country', country::text, 
'match', false::boolean)) AS combined
FROM data
```

But I can't figure out how to do this LEFT JOIN inside a PL/pgSQL function.

The function loops over a cursor, and where a certain condition is met, I need to do this conversion and store it into a variable.

i.e. Inside cursor `cur`, for record `rec`, I have to get corresponding `rec.city_data`, convert it to the new format, and save it to variable  `var_city_data`

How do I do the LEFT JOIN on a `rec`?  Usually inside a record I just call `rec.field_name` and don't need to do any `FROM`...

I tried:

```
FOR rec IN cur LOOP

        -- conditions........

        WITH data AS (
            SELECT cities.key AS city, cities.value AS country
            FROM rec -- I THINK THE ERROR IS SOMEWHERE HERE AND NEXT LINE
            LEFT JOIN jsonb_each_text(rec.city_data::jsonb) cities ON true
            )
        SELECT INTO var_city_data
        jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object('city', city::text, 
                                    'country', country::text, 
                                    'match', false::boolean))
        FROM data;

        RAISE NOTICE 'city_data: %  ', var_city_data;

        -- ... other conditions...
END LOOP;
```

I also tried removing `FROM rec` , doing directly `FROM jsonb_each_text(rec.city_data::jsonb)` etc and I keep getting errors of type `PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

NOTE: this function has to work on PostgreSQL versions 9.6 and 11+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need of `LEFT JOIN` or `WITH` Clause.

Simply try below query:

```sql
FOR rec IN cur LOOP

        -- conditions........

SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_object(
'city', cities.key::text, 
'country', cities.value::text, 
'match', false::boolean)) 
INTO var_city_data
FROM jsonb_each_text(rec.city_data::jsonb) cities(key,value);
    
RAISE NOTICE 'city_data: %  ', var_city_data;

-- ... other conditions...
END LOOP;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=fed71b3088f7cef6e56a01e08e03f34a)